# Bulk Resize Selected Images in Automator

Tags: macos, image-processing, image-resizing, automator

I have a folder containing 1000s of images within various subfolders.

Each image has a number of sizes (e.g. thumbnail, medium, large, original).

I need to bulk resize all of the original images to 1500px, however when I run this through Automator it doesn't just decrease the originals to 1500px, it also increases the thumbnails to 1500px.

Is there any way to decrease any image above 1500px to 1500px without increasing any that are smaller?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your current script.

Comment: I'm just using the scale images quick action